# Простые/примитивные/встроенные Типы в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Дайте, пожалуйста, определения следующим понятиям:

1. Простые типы (*simple types*);
2. Примитивные типы (*primitive types*);
3. Встроенные типы (*built-in types*)

И какие именно типы к этим группам относят.

---

Почему меня это заинтересовало - читая книгу Рихтера "CLR via C#", а именно Главу 5, вижу таблицу примитивных типов, в которой написаны:

- ***Числовые типы*** (***byte..double и decimal***);
- ***bool***;
- ***string***;
- ***object***;
- ***dynamic***.

Но, далее Рихтер уже пишет, что ***decimal*** не является примитивным. Получается противоречие.
Полез я тогда в библиотеку MSDN и нашел следующее:

1. К простым типам относятся: **Числовые типы** и ***bool***;
2. К встроенным типам относят: **Числовые типы**; ***bool***; ***string***; ***object***.
3. К примитивным типам относят: Все **числовые типы** (кроме ***decimal***); ***bool***; 
   ***IntPtr***; ***UIntPtr***.

Ссылки: [1 и 2 пункт](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ya5y69ds.aspx); [3 пункт](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx).

Получается, что Рихтер в таблице хотел показать встроенные типы, но почему-то написал их как примитивные. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Искал в других источниках: там простые/примитивные/встроенные типы - это синонимы.

Comment: Хм. Возможно, это проблемы перевода?

Comment: Смотрел оригинал книги, там также указано, т.е. перевод верный.

Comment: @nuts119, если внимательно посмотреть на перечисленные Вами названия "представителей типов", то все (отбросим Рихтера) становится очевидным.

- примитивные -- это те, которые имеют непосредственную аппаратную поддержку в x86 (ну, может не одной, но "почти одной" машинной командой можно манипулировать их значениями)

- встроенные -- это, понятно, те о которых *компилятор все знает* и может легко генерить код для виртуальной машины

- простые -- насколько понимаю, это не ссылочные типы.

Очевидно, что все примитивные являются простыми и все простые являются встроенными.

--

IMHO все.

Comment: @avp, похоже на правду.
Кстати, нашел где официально употребляется термин "built-in types".
А именно в CLI спецификации. Пункт 1.8.2.2.
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf

Comment: @nuts119, да относитесь Вы ко всему этому академическому (а скорее аспирантско-просветительскому) словоблудию попроще.

Comment: @avp, и все же я надеялся, что эти термины будут конкретно определены в каких-нибудь доках.
Ну а так, пожалуй последую Вашему совету.

Comment: Вопрос пока оставлю висеть открытым. Возможно, кто-нибудь еще напишет интересного.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Канонический источник информации — [официальная спецификация языка](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029). В ней сказано (раздел 4.1 Value types):

> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the **simple types**.
>
> *simple-type*:
>
> - *numeric-type*
> - `bool`
>
> *numeric-type*:
>
> - *integral-type*
> - *floating-point-type*
> - `decimal`

То есть, `decimal` и `bool` является, а `string`, `object` и `dynamic` не является `simple-type`. Тот же список приведён в явном виде в разделе 4.1.4: `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `bool`, `decimal`.

Слово “primitive” употребляется в спецификации всего дважды: в части 1 (Introduction):

> C# has a ***unified type system***. All C# types, including primitive types such as `int` and `double`, inherit from a single root `object` type.

и в части 11 (Structs):

> Just as these predefined types are structs, it is also possible to use structs and operator overloading to implement new “primitive” types in the C# language.

Нигде нету более точного определения, поэтому можно считать, что понятие *primitive type* не формализовано. То же относится и к `built-in`: данный термин вовсе не встречается в спецификации.

Рихтер, судя по всему, позволяет себе несколько вольное обращение с терминами (он настолько крут, что может себе это позволить).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, хотелось бы знать почему именно такие типы (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, bool, decimal) относят к простым?
Насчет примитивных. Хоть понятие и не определено, но такая группа существует (можно проверить через typeof(<Тип>).IsPrimitive, выше по ссылке это написано). И хотелось бы знать, на каких основаниях относят типы к это группе.

Comment: @nuts119: Ну, мне кажется, названия обсуждать не имеет особого смысла. Всё равно что обсуждать, почему грушу не назвали яблоком.

Я думаю, простыми эти типы названы потому, что они не определяются в терминах других. Хотя `decimal`, по идее, можно было бы определить в терминах массивов. Кроме того, `object` и `string` тоже не определяются в терминах других. Так что это скорее мои догадки.

Другой причиной может быть то, что у этих типов самая простая _семантика_: число, символ, да/нет. Семантика остальных типов сложнее.

Answer (score 2):

Так как все еще могут оставаться вопросы, попробую еще ответить.
Если сразу, то:

1. Встроенные (предопределенные) типы:

   - Типы значений:

     - Числовые типы (все):

       - Целочисленные со знаком (sbyte, short, int, long)
       - Целочисленные без знака (byte, ushort, uint, ulong)
       - IEEE-представление с плавающей запятой (float, double)
       - Десятичный с повышенной точностью (decimal)
     - Логический тип (bool)
     - Символы Юникода (char)
   - Ссылочные типы:

     - Строки Юникода (string)
     - Базовый класс для всех типов (object)
2. Простые типы:

   - Числовые типы (все):

     - Целочисленные со знаком (sbyte, short, int, long)
     - Целочисленные без знака (byte, ushort, uint, ulong)
     - IEEE-представление с плавающей запятой (float, double)
     - Десятичный с повышенной точностью (decimal)
   - Логический тип (bool)
   - Символы Юникода (char)
3. Примитивные типы:

   - Числовые типы (без decimal):

     - Целочисленные со знаком (sbyte, short, int, long)
     - Целочисленные без знака (byte, ushort, uint, ulong)
     - IEEE-представление с плавающей запятой (float, double)
   - Логический тип (bool)
   - Символы Юникода (char)
   - System.IntPtr
   - System.UintPtr

Точные определения:

1. Предопределенные типы С# являются псевдонимами типов .NET Framework в пространстве имен System. Показанные ниже два оператора отличаются только синтаксисом:

   ```
   int i = 5;
   System.Int32 i = 5;
   ```
2. Простые типы - встроенные типы значений.
3. Набор предопределенных типов значений, исключая decimal, известен в CLR как примитивные типы. Примитивные типы называются так потому, что они поддерживаются непосредственно через инструкции в скомпилированном коде, которые обычно транслируются в прямую поддержку внутри имеющегося процессора. Например:

   ```
                    // Лежащие в основе шестнадцатеричные представления
   int i = 7;       // Ох7
   bool b = true;   // Ox1
   char с = 'А';    // Ох41
   float f = 0.5f;  // Использует кодирование плавающей точки IEEE
   ```

   Типы System. IntPtr и System. UintPtr также являются примитивными.

Источники:

C# 6.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка. с.56

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, определение примитивного типа должно выглядеть как-то так:

Примитивный тип - это **несоставной** тип данных, тоесть такие типы как int, double, boolean, single, byte и т.д., занимающие в памяти строго определенное количество байт. String, Object. enum уже не примитивные, а составные типы данных, тоесть состоящие из ряда примитивных. Например, string помимо набора символов и указателя на первый символ, хранит еще как минимум свою длину в памяти.

Comment: И, кстати, по приведенному вами методу Type.isPrimitive в msdn написано:

The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

If the current Type represents a generic type, or a type parameter in the definition of a generic type or generic method, this property always returns false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

Comment: @MDJHD, Какие типы относят на MSDN я видел (данную ссылку я приводил в описание вопроса). Или мне надо на что-то обратить внимание?

Насчет примитивных. Ваше определение похоже на правду. Только вот как быть с decimal? Он разве в памяти не занимает определенное количество байт (16)?

Comment: Хм. `object` — тоже несоставной тип данных. Да и `enum`'ы не _состоят из_ нескольких других типов.

Comment: Предположу, что к примитивным типам относятся те типы, которые могут оперироваться инструкциями языка IL.

Например, при сложение двух переменных типа byte выполняется команда add.
А при сложение переменных типа decimal вызывается его специальный метод для сложения.

Это я сказал все в грубой форме. Надеюсь посыл понятен.

Comment: @VladD, почему же объект не составной тип? Он ведь не может целиком влезть в регистр процессора. @nuts119, да как-то так, типы, которые влазят в один регистр процессора и надо считать примитивными, все остальные - составными (или как там правильно переводится generic?). decimal для 64-битного проца также не примитивный, а вот для 128-битного будет уже примитивным.

Comment: @MDJHD: Эээ... Спецификация языка не должна зависеть от того, какая разрядность процессора. Исходя из вашего определения, тип может быть или не быть примитивным. Это какое-то странное определение.

generic, кстати, это не составной тип, а шаблонный (что-то наподобие template'а в C++).

Comment: Нашел в словаре:

generic type -
• родовой тип, параметризованный тип;
• настраиваемый тип. понятие языка
программирования, определяющее класс типов данных, различающихся значениями некоторого параметра или
группы. родовой тип используется
только для описания конкретных типов или других родовых объектов, но
не для определения переменных

Comment: Призовем на помощь http://yandex.by/yandsearch?lr=21015&banerid=123&oprnd=9730752078&text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5, который не долго думая первым резалтом направляет нас праведной рукой в педивикию: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тип_данных

Comment: @MDJHD: Ну вы и источник нашли. Проблема в том, что единого понятия нет, каждый язык называет вещи по-своему. Скажем, такие понятия как, например, pointer и reference в C++ и C# (а также, как я понимаю, в других языках) означают совершенно разные вещи. (То есть pointer в C++ — совсем не то же, что pointer в C#, ну и reference в C++ кардинально отличается от reference в C#.)

Answer (score 0):

**decimal** по определению не может быть простым типом в силу своего строения, там как минимум 2 части есть.
есть ЧПЗ - **real, float, double**
integer - **char, byte, int** 
и все.
**bool** так же не может быть простым типом, ибо понятие **true/false** не является числовым (в отличии от C/C++ где это может быть определено через **#define**) но во многих языках это встроенный тип.
В контексте C# говорить о простых типах вообще можно только с большой натяжкой - это типизированный язык.

Comment: Где пруфы, Билли?

В смысле, вы бы привели в подкрепление своих тезисов ссылки на какую-нибудь документацию, а?

[У Int64 тоже две части есть: старшее и младшее слово. И даже `byte` делится на биты.]

Comment: Хм.. bool сложный тип по-вашему? Только то, что компилятор не пропускает отличные от true/false значения для bool еще не значит, что он не является скажем int32 или byte

Comment: Я вправе не приводить ссылки на прописные истины, ибо это азбука даже не языка, а основ программирования вообще, но если есть сомнения - начать можно с Керниган и Ритчи, Шилдт и другие в том числе Страуструп, очень хорошо пишет В.В.Подбельский (рекомендую).

Comment: > bool так же не может быть простым типом.

@stells2, Можете конкретно указать источник, где это написано? Интересно почитать.
И не понял, зачем Вы здесь указали real?

Comment: еще раз, это определение от обратного но по ссылкам выше найдете точное определение и описание..  
**Простые типы - это только целочисленные и ЧПЗ.**  
Тип **bool** логический тип данных — примитивный тип данных в информатике, которые могут принимать два возможных значения. Присутствует в подавляющем большинстве языков программирования как **самостоятельная сущность или реализуется через численный тип**.  
В подавляющем большинстве языков за истину полагается единица, за ложь — ноль. Даже символьный тип - условность, это обычный целочисленный знаковый или нет тип.

Answer (score 0):

В C# есть два основных типа данных: типы значений и ссылочные типы. Они отличаются по содержимому переменной. Переменные, относящиеся к типу значений, содержат непосредственно значение. А переменные ссылочного типа содержат ссылку на объект.

Числовые типы и bool относят к простым (и иногда называют примитивными, как, например, в учебнике Шилдта), просто потому что их переменные содержат значение, а не ссылаются ни на что + они являются самыми низкоуровневыми элементами данных.

[image]

Comment: позвольте объяснить, за что минус?  
Расскажите, где я ошибся.

Comment: @teanЫЧ минус мой. Речь не о Шилдте (я не считаю нужным обвинять его во всех смертных грехах, даже несмотря на то, что в его книгах находили неточности) 
Речь о том, что ваш ответ никак не отвечает на вопрос о разнице между простыми,встроенными и примитивными типами, о принадлежности к ним decimal и противоречии, упомянутом ТСом в книге Рихтера. Вместо этого выпишете очевидные очевидности про "value types vs reference types". Не обессудьте

Comment: первая строка вопроса автора:
Всем привет! Дайте, пожалуйста, определения следующим понятиям:

    Простые типы (simple types);

Comment: Хм. Шилдт говорит, что простые типы, иногда называют примитивными.
Только вот свойство IsPrimitive, покажет, что как раз не все простые типы и есть примитивные.

Как и говорилось, авторы приведенных здесь книг, вольно обращаются с терминами. Винить, конечно их нельзя, т.к. официальная документация не дает определение данных терминов.